# Android Studio cannot resolve com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.SubscribeOptions.Builder

Tags: java, android, import, eddystone, google-nearby

I am trying to use Google's Nearby Messages API for the first time. I downloaded some source code from GitHub and tried to compile it using Android Studio. There is an import that Android Studio cannot resolve:

```
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.SubscribeOptions;
```

My Gradle file defines the following dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:7.8.0'
```

and this is the `Activity` in which I am using the aforementioned library:

```
package com.example.android.nearbybeacons;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.Nearby;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Message;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.MessageListener;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Strategy;
import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.SubscribeOptions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG =
            MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 100;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 42;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ArrayAdapter<OfferBeacon> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        //Construct a connection to Play Services
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
                .build();

        //When launching from a notification link
        if (BeaconService.ACTION_DISMISS.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            //Fire a clear action to the service
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BeaconService.class);
            intent.setAction(BeaconService.ACTION_DISMISS);
            startService(intent);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Initiate connection to Play Services
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        //The location permission is required on API 23+ to obtain BLE scan results
        int result = ActivityCompat
                .checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Ask for the location permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Tear down Play Services connection
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Un-subscribing…");
            Nearby.Messages.unsubscribe(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    mMessageListener);
            mAdapter.clear();

            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    // This is called in response to a button tap in the system permissions dialog.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Permission granted or error resolved successfully then we proceed
                // with publish and subscribe..
                subscribe();
            } else {
                // This may mean that user had rejected to grant nearby permission.
                showToast("Failed to resolve error with code " + resultCode);
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                showToast("We need location permission to get scan results!");
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        OfferBeacon item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
        showToast(item.offer);
    }

    /* Nearby Messages Callbacks */

    //NOTE: These callbacks are NOT triggered on the main thread!
    private MessageListener mMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
        // Called each time a new message is discovered nearby.
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Found message: " + message);
            final OfferBeacon beacon = new OfferBeacon(message);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mAdapter.add(beacon);
                }
            });
        }
        // Called when the publisher (beacon) is no longer nearby.
        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Lost message: " + message);
            final OfferBeacon beacon = new OfferBeacon(message);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mAdapter.remove(beacon);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    /* API Client Callbacks */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        //Once connected, we have to check that the user has opted in
        Runnable runOnSuccess = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Subscribe once user permission is verified
                subscribe();
            }
        };
        ResultCallback<Status> callback =
                new ErrorCheckingCallback(runOnSuccess);
        Nearby.Messages.getPermissionStatus(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(callback);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnConnectionSuspended");
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.w(TAG, "OnConnectionFailed");
    }
    private void subscribe() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Subscribing…");
        SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
                .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
                .build();
        //Active subscription for foreground messages
        Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient,
                mMessageListener, options);
        //Passive subscription for background messages
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, BeaconService.class);
        PendingIntent trigger = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        ResultCallback<Status> callback = new BackgroundRegisterCallback();
        Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, trigger, options)
                .setResultCallback(callback);
    }
    private class BackgroundRegisterCallback implements ResultCallback<Status> {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            //Validate if we were able to register for background scans
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Background Register Success!");
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Background Register Error ("
                        + status.getStatusCode() + "): "
                        + status.getStatusMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    //ResultCallback triggered when to handle Nearby permissions check
    private class ErrorCheckingCallback implements ResultCallback<Status> {
        private final Runnable runOnSuccess;

        private ErrorCheckingCallback(@Nullable Runnable runOnSuccess) {
            this.runOnSuccess = runOnSuccess;
        }
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Permission status succeeded.");
                if (runOnSuccess != null) {
                    runOnSuccess.run();
                }
            } else {
                // Currently, the only resolvable error is that the device is not opted
                // in to Nearby. Starting the resolution displays an opt-in dialog.
                if (status.hasResolution()) {
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                                REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        showToastAndLog(Log.ERROR, "Request failed with exception: " + e);
                    }
                } else {
                    showToastAndLog(Log.ERROR, "Request failed with : " + status);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void showToastAndLog(int logLevel, String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.println(logLevel, TAG, message);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you will be able to resolve this by updating the Play Services version you are using from v7.8.0 to v8.4.0 (the latest version as of this answer date). The Nearby APIs were introduced in v7.8.0, at which time subscription could be accomplished using a method signature of the form

```
subscribe(GoogleApiClient, MessageListener, Strategy)
```

However, this method is now (in v8.4.0) marked as deprecated, and a new method with the following signature is recommended in its place:

```
subscribe (GoogleApiClient, MessageListener, SubscribeOptions)
```

Based on this information it seems fairly likely that the `SubscribeOptions` type was introduced whenever the previously-described deprecation took place, which was clearly post-v7.8.0.

See [these docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/Messages.html#public-methods) for reference.